# how to copy/move pdf files available in one document library to another library/folder

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, sharepoint-online

I have a Document library with PDF files. I am trying to move this file to another document library using SPD 2013 Workflow. But it is not copied to the destination.